# omitting verbs is and are

Tags: ellipsis

Omitting verbs, can I say "Two tangos dead", "Two tangos dead ahead", "Two tangos coming", "Two tanks down", "Two tanks over there" ?

Is it colloquially acceptable to omit "is", "are" verbs like above?

(Tango means target as a military term)

Answer (score 2):

Colloquially, yes, that's how people often talk, especially something like a warning.

> "Car coming!"

It also happens in headlines and titles, but would be unusual in any other context, eg when telling a story.

Comment: Maybe, is "Game over" to do with my question as well?

Comment: Sort of, @Zenith. It's more like the "headlines and titles" thing - that also extends to information messages. Although people do say "Game over", I don't think this is actually a shortened sentence ("The game is over") but more a catch-phrase, taken from the message displayed at the end of a computer game. I don't think somebody would remark "Game finished" - though they might well say "Game's finished", with the article omitted, but not the verb.

Answer (score 0):

Military commands, orders, and general language is very concise.

- "Enemy down!"
- "Enemy sighted!"
- "Tank 70%°"
- "Medic!"
- "Bravo left hill; Alpha on me!"

Military tends to shorten all that can be shortened for quick strategic manipulation and high effectiveness.

Comment: That may be true, but I don't think tthere's anything particularly military here. See my answer.